# Julia - Metaprogramming for using several modules

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I'm using Julia to autograde students' work. I have all of their files `Student1.jl`, `Student2.jl`, etc. as separate modules `Student1`, `Student2`, etc in a directory that is part of `LOAD_PATH`. What I want to be able to do works completely fine in the REPL, but fails in a file.

```
macro Student(number)
    return Meta.parse("Main.Student$number")
end

using Student1
@Student(1).call_function(inputs)
```

works completely fine in the REPL. However, since I'm running this in a script, I need to be able to include the modules with more metaprogramming that is currently not working. I would have thought that the exact same script above would have worked in a file `Autograder.jl` by calling

```
@eval(using Student1)
@Student(1).call_function(inputs)
```

in a `module Autograder`. But I get either an `UndefVarError: Student1 not defined` or `LoadError: cannot replace module Student1 during compilation` depending on how I tweak things.

Is there something small in Julia metaprogramming I'm missing here to make this autograding system work out? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code just as you have written works for me on julia versions 1.1.0, 1.3.1, 1.5.1, 1.6.0 and 1.7.0. By that I mean, if I add an `inputs` variable and put your first code block in a file `Autograder.jl` and run `JULIA_LOAD_PATH="modules:$JULIA_LOAD_PATH" julia Autograder.jl` with the student modules in the `modules` directory I get the output of the `call_function` function in the `Student1` module.

However if `Autograder.jl` actually contains a module then the `Student$number` module is not required into `Main` and your macro needs to be modified accordingly:

```
module Autograder
macro Student(number)
    return Meta.parse("Student$number") # or "Autograder.Student$number"
end

inputs = []
@eval(using Student1)
@Student(1).call_function(inputs)
end
```

Personally I wouldn't use a macro to accomplish this, here is one possible alternative:

```
student(id) = Base.require(Main, Symbol("Student$(id)"))
let student_module = student(1)
    student_module.call_function(inputs)
end
```

or without modifying the `LOAD_PATH`:

```
student(id) = include("modules/Student$(id).jl")
let student_module = student(1)
    student_module.call_function(inputs)
end
```

Comment: Very interesting. I agree that the let block seems like a good way forward. However, if I run your last block of code in a function, I get a world age error. It is fixed by using `Base.invokelatest()` following the advice from here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/world-age-problem/27759/2, but the other commenters there got me worried that maybe this isn't so idiomatic. What do you think?

Comment: You should definitely stop and think before using `invokelatest`, it's very rarely necessary in "normal" Julia code. However, what you're doing is dynamically loading files and then testing them, using `invokelatest` makes sense here. You could avoid `invokelatest` by separating the loading and the running of the tests but that doesn't really make sense to me here, you probably want to handle syntax errors etc. in the same place before "grading". Have a look at when `invokelatest` is used in `Base` to get a feel for it (e.g. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/download.jl).

Comment: The `let` block is of course not necessary and only intended as a proxy for whatever block you want here, maybe you want to map over a range of student ids, or perhaps it makes more sense to iterate over all the paths in `modules` now that the code is `include`ed directly.

Comment: That's a fair point - this isn't meant to be a performance-heavy application, and this autograding idea is a bit outside normal Julia module usage anyway. Indeed the student's can turn in code with syntax errors preventing even compilation, and my autograder will still complete and give them a grade nonetheless.